# Code::Blocks debbuger failure

Tags: c++, debugging, ubuntu, codeblocks

Before explaining my problem:
My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bits with 4GB RAM.
My IDE is Code::Blocks 12.11(I've had the same problem with 10.05)
I'm using the GNU GCC Compiler with the -g flag and the -std=c++0x flag.

When trying to debug this program:

```
using namespace std;

#include<iostream>

int main(){

int n=10;

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    int ax=i;
    while(ax) ax--;
    cout<<i;
}


return 0;
}
```

I can't get anything to happen,if I try the "Run to cursor" command or if I try to use breakpoints. They just get skipped and my program finishes running.

This is what I get in the debugger log:

Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target:
Release
Adding source dir: /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/
Adding source dir: /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/
Adding file: /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr
Changing directory to: /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/.
Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:
Starting debugger: /usr/bin/gdb -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args    /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Reading symbols from /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
Temporary breakpoint 2 ("/home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/main.cpp:10) pending.
[Inferior 1 (process 13381) exited normally]
Debugger finished with status 0

If anyone wants to suggest a solution that implies using the terminal, please do it in the most noob-orieted terms you can find!
PS: How to add breaklines on stack-overflow when asking a question?(Solved-Thanks!)

Comment: To add break lines, add 2 spaces at the end of the line.

Comment: it seems that it didn't really generate the debuginfo. can you use 'file' command to check your output binary?

Comment: @tristan How could I add the 'file' command?(please keep it noob-oriented!)

Comment: no. I mean run "file  /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr
" on command line

Comment: This is what is shows:
file /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr
/home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x7da8c5cff4af5082d82eecc3ede59a5920b253a0, stripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reading symbols from /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr...(no
>   debugging symbols found)...done.

This means you didn't have the -g option during compilation.

UPDATE:

```
file /home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr 

/home/classius/CodeBlocks/Dr/bin/Release/Dr: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x7da8c5cff4af5082d82eecc3ede59a5920b253a0, stripped
```

So it's 'stripped', which means -g option was not really used. You may recheck your compiler config or try to build the Debug version?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do have the -g option checked at compiler and debbuger

Comment: but gdb says it doesn't have debugging symbol. Please check how it's compiled

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: The -g option is checked. But the interesting thing is that I have gone to Build->Select Target and checked debug instead of release and now it works yay :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in settings menu  choose debugger then gdb-cdb tab and then reset default